# Can a process read its own stdout/stderr?

Tags: c, macos, file-descriptor

I wanted to capture the output of `NSLog` from Objective-C and put the contents in a text view. For that I created a background thread that would use `poll` on `STDERR_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` like this:

```
struct pollfd fds[2] =  {
  {.fd = STDERR_FILENO, .events = POLLIN },
  {.fd = STDOUT_FILENO, .events = POLLIN }
};
const size_t nfds = sizeof(fds) / sizeof(fds[0]);
int result = poll(fds, nfds, -1);
```

But the call blocks permanently, even if i call some `printf`'s before calling `poll`. Is it actually possible to use `STDERR_FILENO`/`STDOUT_FILENO` for reading to capture the contents, or since they are pseudo file descriptors, it does not work this way?

Comment: You should be able to do that by setting the filedescriptors to some buffer.. I will let someone better at the POSIX API write a full answer.

Comment: They are real file descriptors. You can `fdopen()` them and so on. No, you cannot read back what you wrote, unless you seek back; this is how *all* files work. The two big problems being (1) that whether you can or cannot seek back depends on whether the user has redirected them to a disk file or not, and (2) a file descriptor has one and only one position; if you seek back in order to read what you wrote, you run the risk that a new write would overwite previously written data.

Comment: @AlexP nice explanation, did not consider seeking. So can I overcome this by duplicating these file descriptors somehow? Man page for dup2 states that the duplicated handle shares the offset, so I assume that wont help.

Comment: A file has **only one position**. When you write new data at the end of the file, the position is just after the last written byte. You can seek (*if* you can seek) back, but then you reset the writing position together with the reading position. Duplicating won't help; as the manual page says, "the object referenced by the descriptor does not distinguish between [the old descriptor] and [the new descriptor] in any way". BTW, why don't you simply redirect stdout and stderr to a disk file?

Comment: @AlexP yep, saw that in the man page, ok dead end then. I had always perceived that stdin/stderr are more like pipes, but if they are file descriptors, then yeah your explanation makes perfect sense, thanks.

Comment: A file descriptor *can* refer to a pipe. You *don't know* what "underlying object" corresponds to stdout and stderr. It may be a terminal, it may be a pipe, it may be a disk file. (And the reading and writing ends of a pipe have different file descriptors.) What you can do is close stdout and stderr, create a pipe, `dup2()` the writing end of the pipe to fd 1 and 2, and read the other end of the pipe. Preferably in a separate thread or (much easier) in a separate process. Please consider and manage the original file descriptors, because the user may expect that redirections etc. work.